# Help with SQLite query

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm writing an application for android and have a fairly simple SQLite3 database (see pic), but I'm having a lot of trouble with a specific query.

Here's (a part of) the database. Note: there's a one-to-many relationship here. A player can have many events but only 1 player for each event.

[image: Table model]

I want to have a list of **all** the players, but I need to order this list of all players by whether they have an event that has it's `Diagnosed` attribute set to false or not(i.e. All players with an "Undiagnosed" event go at the top, all other players come after). If they have more than one "Undiagnosed" event than the newest one is used.

That's the trickiest part of the query. After that the players with the "Undiagnosed" events need to be ordered by their 'Magnitude' attribute (int), and the other players (any player that doesn't have any "undiagnosed" events) need to be ordered by their last name.

Here's an example of the list I need:

- Player    <--1 Undiagnosed event (100 magnitude)
- Player    <--2 Undiagnosed events (Newest one 75 magnitude)
- Player    <--1 Undiagnosed event (50 magnitude)
- Player    <-- No Undiagnosed Events (Name: Johnny Appleseed)
- Player    <-- No Undiagnosed Events (Name: Jim Zebra)

The only way I can think of doing this is by using 2 separate queries (one for "Undiagnosed" players and another for everyone else) but I don't think that's the best way of doing this.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Ok so here's the query that's mostly working now.

```
select player.PlayerID, player.fname, player.lname, stats.diagcount, topmag.magnitude 
from player left outer join (
select playerid, MIN(diagnosed) as diagcount
from events group by playerid
)as stats on player.playerid = stats.playerid
left outer join (
select playerid,max(magnitude) as magnitude
from events group by playerid
)as topmag on player.playerid=topmag.playerid
order by CASE WHEN stats.diagcount Is NULL Then 1 Else 0 End,stats.diagcount,topmag.magnitude,lname;
```

Only problem now is that players at the bottom of the list (Players without any diagnosed events) are being sorted by their most recent event magnitude and not by last name.

Comment: `"The only way I can think of doing this is by using 2 separate queries (one for "Undiagnosed" players and another for everyone else) but I don't think that's the best way of doing this."`  Don't assume that a query consisting of inline views and unions is somehow flawed from the get-go or would perform poorly--the optimizer can sometimes have an easier time with such queries, and they're certainly more legible and maintainable because the discrete subsets are more clearly represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
select player.fname, player.lname, stats.diagcount, topmag.highest
from player left outer join (
     select playerid, count(time) as diagcount
     from events group by playerid
)as stats on player.playerid = stats.playerid
left outer join (
   select playerid,max(magnitude) as highest
    from events group by playerid
)as topmag on player.playerid=topmag.playerid
order by stats.diagcount,topmag.highest,lname
```

dunno whats possible in sqllite but i think something like that might work, if you get errors post them and I will see what I can do

If you want to eliminate sorting by magnitude on player whos events are diagnosed then you could eliminate them from the sub queries..

```
select player.fname, player.lname, stats.diagcount, topmag.highest
from player left outer join (
     select playerid, count(time) as diagcount
     from events 
     where diagnosed = 0
     group by playerid
)as stats on player.playerid = stats.playerid
left outer join (
   select playerid,max(magnitude) as highest
    from events 
    where diagnosed = 0
    group by playerid
)as topmag on player.playerid=topmag.playerid
order by stats.diagcount,topmag.highest,lname
```

sorry I might have the diagnosed thing the wrong way round (as in maybe it should be diagnosed = 1)

Comment: Hey @Gordatron. Thanks for the help! We did some tweaking on your query (which is very good and got us on the right track!) and it's working very well. I'll post the updated code in the question. There's just one problem... A player who has been diagnosed is also sorted by their magnitude (if they HAD an event) and not by their last name. Any way to do `if diagnosed==1 then order by lname`? I'll still mark this as the answer, thanks!

Comment: updated the answer with one possible option.. it will not return any information about diagnosed events